# Get maximal values of several fields for each day in local time

Tags: postgresql

### We have

A wide-format PostgreSQL table of time series data from various sensors:

| `datetime` | `s_1` | ... | `s_n` | Note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **20230101T10:00:00Z** | **3.00** | ... | null |  |
| **20230101T11:00:00Z** | 2.00 | ... | **10.0** |  |
| 20230101T12:00:00Z | 1.00 | ... | null |  |
| **20230101T23:00:00Z** | **4.00** | ... | null | next day in tz=Europe/Berlin! |
| 20230102T10:00:00Z | 2.00 | ... | null |  |
| **20230102T10:00:00Z** | 1.00 | ... | **9.3** |  |

`datetime` is a UTC-timestamp and `s_i` are floats. Marked as bold are the sought-after
values. In practice, `n` is a few 100.

### We want

An SQL query (preferably one, avoiding intermediate tables) which yields a table in
long format containing for each sensor `s_i` its maximal (non-null) value for each day
in *local* time (Europe/Berlin, +01:00/+02:00 wrt UTC during normal/DST time):

| `datetime` | `variable` | `value` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20230101T10:00:00Z | `s_1` | 3.00 |
| 20230101T23:00:00Z | `s_1` | 4.00 |
| 20230101T11:00:00Z | `s_n` | 10.00 |
| 20230102T10:00:00Z | `s_n` | 9.3 |

Less-optimal alternative would be the same table in wide format:

| `datetime` | `s_1` | ... | `s_n` | Note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230101T10:00:00Z | **3.00** | ... | null |  |
| 20230101T11:00:00Z | null | ... | **10.0** | non-maximal value for `s_1` set to null! |
| 20230101T23:00:00Z | **4.00** | ... | null |  |
| 20230102T10:00:00Z | null | ... | **9.3** | non-maximal value for `s_1` set to null! |

### What we tried

Actually a lot. We got closes to a solution with the query

```sql
SELECT 
    date (timezone('Europe/Berlin', datetime))::timestamptz as datetime, 
    MAX (s_1) as s_1_max, 
    MAX (s_n) as s_n_max
FROM table
GROUP BY date (timezone('Europe/Berlin', datetime))
```

which yields a wide-format table of this form:

| `datetime` | `s_1_max` | ... | `s_n_max` | Note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230101T00:00:00Z | **3.00** | ... | **10.0** | one row per day, time lost |
| 20230102T00:00:00Z | **4.00** | ... | **9.3** | one row per day, time lost |

Yet, the time information is lost (all times set to 00:00:00) here, and all sought-after
maximal values are aggregated in one row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a UTC timezone in postgresql to EST (local time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36341060/convert-a-utc-timezone-in-postgresql-to-est-local-time)  (You just need to change the timezone 'EST' to the correct one...)

Comment: @Luuk Unfortunately, it doesn't. The question is not how to convert time zones (we know how to do it), but how to GROUP BY a date extracted from a timestamp, without loosing the time associated with that time stamp. At least considering our best attempt I showed. There may be completely different ways, though.

Comment: "how to GROUP BY a date extracted from a timestamp, without loosing the time"  Group by date, without loosing the time is NOT possible.

Comment: @Luuk I am aware of this. Otherwise we would have solved the problem ;) I am rather looking for an alternative which achives our aim with difference query.

Comment: Can you create a [DBFIDDLe](https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30) with the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Unpivot like here: [Equivalent to unpivot() in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128737/equivalent-to-unpivot-in-postgresql)
- assign dates like you did it
- rank in partitions
- take rows with highest rank

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/x-V0_m0D)

```
select datetime, col, val 
from (
    select datetime, col, val, 
           rank() over (partition by dt, col order by val desc) rnk 
    from ( 
        select datetime,
               date(timezone('Europe/Berlin', datetime)) dt,
               unnest(array['s_1', 's_2']) as col,
               unnest(array[s_1, s_2]) as val
        from tbl t) unpivoted
    where val is not null ) ranked
where rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your query solved the problem! Clever combination of PARTITION BY, ORDER and RANK for finding the maximum. I'll keep the "unpivot" part in mind, that we come in handy in other situations, too!

Answer (score 0):

When doing:

```
select date(timezone('Europe/Berlin','20230101T10:00:00Z'))::timestamptz;
```

You will convert the datetime value to a date, which looses time (`2023-01-01 00:00:00+01`).

do this:

```
select (timezone('Europe/Berlin','20230101T10:00:00Z'))::timestamptz;
```

results in: `2023-01-01 11:00:00+01`, which is the converted (date)time in Berlin-timezone.

Comment: sure, omitting the call to date(...) retains the time. Yet as we GROUPBY date(...), that date(...) must also appear in the SELECT. So this works as one-liner, but not in the context of the last SQL query I posted.

Comment: @ChristianHoffmann: It's up to you to correct the SQL, and also leave the `date()` from the GROUP BY`   (Which seems obvious to /me)

Comment: Sure, I can drop it the date() from both the SELECT and the GROUP BY to avoid SQL errors. But that would compromise our ultimate aim: to find the maximum value for each sensor in each day. That is the central part of my question.

Comment: But you need/want to group on German days? Then you should first convert to a datetime in German, and only after that do the conversion to date (without time).